# Is it possible to use Azure Alerts without a resource?

Tags: azure-devops

Our current configuration uses Netlify to deploy our front-end application, Bitbucket to host our repo's and Azure Devops to automate the build/release process. I want to integrate Azure Alerts in this proces (to notify devs on deployment status) but when I go to Alerts I need to select an resource. And to create a resource we need to setup a payment plant. So my question is, is it possible to create an Alert without an resource? Perhaps through the CLI or API?

Answer (score 0):

To create an Azure Alerts, a subscription and a resource group are required. We have no any method to create an alert without the subscription and resource group.

In your case, if you want to notify developers on deployment status, you can add a notification on Azure DevOps. you can navigate to "**Project Settings**" > "**Notifications**" to add a new notification via the "**+ New subscription**" button.

To view more details, you can see "[**Manage notifications for a team, group, or organization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops)".

[image]